# Excel VBA Userform Initialize populates Listbox but shows random selected items

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, selecteditem

I'm using Excel 2013.  I have a "BeforeDoubleClick" event that shows a userform with some listboxes.  The user double clicks any cell and the userform intializes and populates the listboxes, however when the userform is launched the listbox shows a couple of the items as highlighted (already selected, even though I haven't selected anything yet):

[image]

This is the code to load the listbox when userform is initialized:

```
For Each cel In rng.Cells
  With cel
  If .Value <> "" Then
    lstPEOPLE.AddItem .Value
  End If
  End With
Next cel
```

Obviously the listbox should be clear of any selections on initialization.  This doesn't happen all the time - it seems to happen when randomly double-clicking cells.  Thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: have you thought of using a ComboBox that references a Table with the Names instead of a range of cells?  Then you could just use the `.RowSource` on the BeforeDoubleClick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set all of the names in that list to a table you could just use the following code in the `BeforeDoubleClick` event:

`lstPeople.RowSource="Insert Table Name Here"`

Comment: Glad I could help.